# XML and XSLT - separate node includes commas

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XML and XSLT. I'm trying to separate a specific node in an XML file, separated with commas. I've seen a code that does it, and I tried to combine it in my XSLT file. It works, but the output contains all the nodes, and ignores my wished path. 
This is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fortnight>
    <hero>
        <name>Guardian</name>
        <characters>Bull,Knox,Penny</characters>
        <rarities>Rare,Epic,Legendary</rarities>
    </hero>

    <hero>
        <name>Deadly Blade</name>
        <characters>Crash,Scorpion</characters>
        <rarities>Epic,Legendary</rarities>
    </hero>

    <hero>
        <name>Enforcer</name>
        <characters>Grizzly</characters>
        <rarities>Uncommon,Rare,Epic,Legendary</rarities>
    </hero>
</fortnight>
```

and this is my XSLT file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <characters>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hero" />

            <xsl:value-of select="characters" />

        </characters>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
            <character name="character">
                <xsl:value-of select=
      "substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>
            </character>

            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I adjust my XSLT to create an output file, only with the "characters" node, and if a node contains commas, it will separate them in the output?

Comment: You might want to show your expected output in your question, but I think you just need to replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="hero" />` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="hero/characters" />` (and drop the `<xsl:value-of select="characters" />`)

Comment: I expanded on my comment in an answer, to explain why this is the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="hero" />` you select all the child `hero` elements under `fortnight` and then XSLT looks for templates to apply to them. However, there are no templates matching `hero` in your XSLT. When this happens, XSLT's [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule) apply. In this case, the following template would be applied

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

So, effectively, it is going to select everything in your XML until it gets to the text nodes. Not just the text nodes under `characters`, but all text nodes.

What you need to do, is target only the nodes you wish to split. That means replacing `<xsl:apply-templates select="hero" />` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="hero/characters" />`.

Also note the line `<xsl:value-of select="characters" />` can be removed. As this is in the template matching `fortnight` This would only select `characters` elements that were a direct child of `fortnight` of which there are none.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't shown us the wanted result from the transformation, I believe **this transformation might be useful**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <characters><xsl:apply-templates/></characters>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="characters/text()" name="split">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
            <character name="character">
                <xsl:value-of select=
                    "substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>
            </character>

            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
                    "substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the provided source xml document**:

```
<fortnight>
    <hero>
        <name>Guardian</name>
        <characters>Bull,Knox,Penny</characters>
        <rarities>Rare,Epic,Legendary</rarities>
    </hero>
    <hero>
        <name>Deadly Blade</name>
        <characters>Crash,Scorpion</characters>
        <rarities>Epic,Legendary</rarities>
    </hero>
    <hero>
        <name>Enforcer</name>
        <characters>Grizzly</characters>
        <rarities>Uncommon,Rare,Epic,Legendary</rarities>
    </hero>
</fortnight>
```

**the (most-likely) wanted result is produced**:

```
<characters>
   <character name="character">Bull</character>
   <character name="character">Knox</character>
   <character name="character">Penny</character>
   <character name="character">Crash</character>
   <character name="character">Scorpion</character>
   <character name="character">Grizzly</character>
</characters>
```

Comment: This is the wanted result. What's the difference between your answer and Tim's answer? I thought the only problem was the xpath.

Comment: We use the so called "push style" -- do not actively direct the control of the transformation -- such as via `<xsl:apply-templates select="someNodeSet"/>` but leave the XSLT processing model do the work for us and select our templates for execution. While in Tim's answer he specifies what nodes he wants templates to be applied upon, in contrast in this answer we specify what nodes should be excluded from the default processing of the XSLT processing model (such as the empty body of `<xsl:template match="text()"/>`). Generaly the push style provides more flexibility and could be more compact